# How can I determine which redirect to make in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, controller

I have two paths that my application can take.

**Path 1: Is editing a valid record.**

1. User goes to `persons#show`
2. User clicks edit to go to `persons#edit`
3. After update leads back to `persons#show`

**Path 2: Is editing an invalid record.**

1. User goes to `persons#invalid_records`
2. User clicks edit to go to `persons#edit`
3. After update (if it succeeds) leads back to `persons#show`

How can I have *Path 2* end up back at `persons#invalid_records` instead of `persons#show`?

**edit posting routes as requested:**

```
resources :persons do
  scope module: :persons do
    resources :notes
    resources :reports
  end
  collection do
    match 'invalid_records' => 'persons#invalid_records', via [:get], as :invalid_records
  end
  member do
    get 'transactions'
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the routes?

Comment: I would add a parameter saying which page i'd come from.

Comment: @Pavan, does my edit contain the information you were looking for?

Comment: By looking at the routes, putting `redirect_to invalid_records_path` in the controller method should work I guess

Comment: @Pavan, except everytime I update I don't wish to do that. I'm guessing I'll have to try and implement Max Williams suggestion.

Comment: i'm with @MaxWilliams, easiest way is add a hidden field that you pass along / keep of track of to figure out where to return to.  Same sort of idea as when you login.

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to post an answer to help get anyone started that might be confused. Thanks to @MaxWilliams for the idea.

I added the following...

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_person_path(record, :invalid_record => true) %>
```

along with this hidden field on my `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= f.hidden_field :invalid_record, :value => params[:invalid_record] %>
```

Finally on the `persons_controller.rb`.

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @person.update(person_params)
      if params[:person][:invalid_record] == true
         #...
      else
         #...
      end
    else
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```